# Which port must i set in heroku flask app?

Tags: flask, heroku, gunicorn

Heroku can't find port for Flask app.
I have tried

```
app.run(port=int(os.environ.get('PORT')))
app.run(port=5000) # and 8000
app.run()
```

Every time i get in logs such message

```
2022-07-14T16:10:27.904518+00:00 app[web.1]: Address already in use
2022-07-14T16:10:27.904523+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 12755 is in use by another program. 
Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
```

Comment: You must use the first option, with the `PORT` environment variable. Nobody else should be using that port. Are you trying to bind to it multiple times? What is in your `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris Procfile **web gunicorn app:app**

Comment: i needed to add if __name__ == '__main__' 
my mistake